# Ubuntu Ethernet problem

Tags: networking, internet, suspend, ethernet

I have a problem on my Ubuntu 16.04

Ethernet only working after resume from suspend. When I boot up my PC, the Ethernet won't work. I tried it from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.10 but it's always the same problem. My friend has the same PC with the same issue.

Can someone help me please? :)

[My PC](https://www.amazon.de/Gaming-PC-Computer-Bulldozer-Six-Core-6x3-5GHz/dp/B01C2T8Q20/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1486404154&sr=8-2&keywords=shinobee%20fx%206300) (sorry, it's not in English)

Comment: If you have the same problem in Windows, it's hardware.

Comment: I know it's the hardware... in Windows it's working :(